# Dropdown Menus work only on Homepage, in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have Created a WordPress theme, and ran into a weird issue recently. Probably, after some Google Chrome Update.

The issue is: the dropdown, after hovering on certain items on menu, appears only on homepage.
It doesn't appear on any other page. Although, its there in the source code.

Demo -> [inkhive](http://demo.inkhive.com/bose/)

I have investigated Javascript which triggers the dropdown:

```
jQuery('#site-navigation li').find('ul').hide();
        jQuery('#site-navigation li').hover(
            function(){
                jQuery(this).find('> ul').slideDown('fast');
            },
            function(){
                jQuery(this).find('ul').hide();
            });
```

The Javascript is doing its job, verified from Inspect Element.

Can Anyone help me understand or figure out the issue?

Comment: `Probably, after some Google Chrome Update.` More probably because you need to set `z-index` for menu_item LI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has nothing do with the code, and was fixed after Google Chrome was updated. There was some issue with their rendering engine(Webkit).

Comment: chrome's rendering engine is Blink, not WebKit